# Is it true that any one-to-one continuous mapping between two topological spaces is a homeomorphism?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

I was thinking if it always true that any one-to-one continuous mapping between two topological spaces is a homeomorphism? Are there any other conditions which imply homeomorphism?

Comment: You say "one-to-one" but then mention "onto". Is this supposed to be bijective?

Comment: Sorry I will edit it

Comment: Ah okay so not necessarily bijective?

Comment: @CameronWilliams yeah

Comment: This is definitely a duplicate. The answer is no. For instance, consider $[0,1[\to S^1: t \mapsto \exp(2\pi i t)$ which is a continuous bijection which is not a homeomorphism (because $S^1$ is compact and $[0,1[$ is not).

Comment: On the other hand, a continuous bijection from a compact space to a Hausdorff space will automatically be a homeomorphism.

Comment: @QuantumSpace has already answered your question. So it's automatically not a homeomorphism in general because you will very possibly miss a lot of the target space. You'll end up restricting to the image of your original space within the second space. But there are plenty of continuous bijections that do not have continuous image.

Comment: @QuantumSpace I did not understand that notation of [0,1[, can you please explain that part?

Comment: The closed interval $[0,1]$ in which you remove $1$. Maybe you are used to the notation $[0,1)$. Another way to write it would be $\{x \in \mathbb{R}: 0 \leq x < 1\}.$